# Unable to Connect to Team City server

Tags: tfs, build, teamcity

What can be the issue when I am getting this behavior out of TeamCity.

background: TeamCity was installed properly. Had a Build agent work with multiple Build configurations successfully. TC agent communicating with TFS and getting the code properly. Everything was good until we had issues with TFS server which went down for a couple of days. Since then we are seeing following issues with TeamCity

1. Logged into TeamCity server to see that http:localhost does not get the Team city admin console any more.
2. The services are running (tried restarting the services both server and agent) but I get message "Unable to connect to Team City server" from the system tray notifier
3. The code folders that had the TFS code pulled, do not have the code any more from last time.

Basically we are not able to do anything with TeamCity.. unable to access the UI. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked IIS to see if a website has taken over the port TeamCity normally uses?

Comment: I changed the port number to a different one at C:\TeamCity\conf\server.xml and restarted the services. That fixed it. But my agents are disconnected. Is there a way I can make them active again? There seems to be no easy way (button?) that does this.

Comment: @ZVenue you also have to change the port in the agent config